# Subtracting the current and previous item in a list

Tags: python

It is very common to write a loop and remember the previous.

I want a generator that does that for me. Something like:

```
import operator

def foo(it):
    it = iter(it)
    f = it.next()
    for s in it:
        yield f, s
        f = s
```

Now subtract pair-wise.

```
L = [0, 3, 4, 10, 2, 3]

print list(foo(L))
print [x[1] - x[0] for x in foo(L)]
print map(lambda x: -operator.sub(*x), foo(L)) # SAME
```

**Outputs:**

```
[(0, 3), (3, 4), (4, 10), (10, 2), (2, 3)]
[3, 1, 6, -8, 1]
[3, 1, 6, -8, 1]
```

- What is a good name for this operation?
- What is a better way to write this?
- Is there a built-in function that does something similar?
- Trying to use 'map' didn't simplify it. What does?

Comment: The list comprehension is already trivially simple, and it's the obvious and natural way to do this.  Going from that to the much more obscure `map` suggests you're overthinking this.  The generator function is also already simple and straightforward.

Comment: it's looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram, aka ngram when n is 2

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
[y - x for x,y in zip(L,L[1:])]
```

Comment: How smart you are

Answer (score 4):

```
l = [(0,3), (3,4), (4,10), (10,2), (2,3)]
print [(y-x) for (x,y) in l]
```

Outputs: [3, 1, 6, -8, 1]

Comment: The construct used in the print statement is called a "list comprehension."

Answer (score 4):

[Recipe from iterools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip, tee
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

and then:

```
>>> L = [0, 3, 4, 10, 2, 3]
>>> [b - a for a, b in pairwise(L)]
[3, 1, 6, -8, 1]
```

[EDIT]

Also, this works (Python < 3):

```
>>> map(lambda(a, b):b - a, pairwise(L))
```